# positon:fixed collapsing elements

Tags: css, html, position, fixed

i'm doing my first webpage, so i need sticky social buttons on the page, so i used this html:

```
<div class="overlay">
        <img src="aynilogopng.png" width="200px" align="left" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" />
        <a target="_blank" href="https://web.facebook.com/ayniproducciones/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a><br>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/ayniproduccionessac" class="fa fa-youtube"></a><br>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://vimeo.com/user7051425" class="fa fa-vimeo"></a>
    </div>
```

and this css:

```
.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;}

.fa {
position: fixed;
padding: 17px;
font-size: 30px;
width: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 10px 2px;
border-radius: 50%;
right: 0;
margin-right: 10px;}

.fa-facebook {
background: #3B5998;
color: white;}
```

i want the buttons to scroll down as the user do, the way i figure this was with position:fixed; but the buttons are collapsing, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `position: fixed;` on the main wrapper, not the child items. Take a look at the following example. I recently provided this to someone else too.

```css
#social-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
}

.social {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.social:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.social a {
  display: block;
}

.social img {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

p {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="social-container">
  <div class="social">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png" class="facebook" alt="Facebook Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/-van-nederland-elgie-gaat-haar-ontwikkeling-posten-op-twitter-24.png" class="twitter" alt="Twitter Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://midflokkurinn.is/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/250ig.png" class="insta" alt="Instagram Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```